# How to add data items to a List<Struct>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following struct defined in a user control:

```
public struct ColumnData
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnDataItem { get; set; }
    public bool ColumnIsHyperLink { get; set; }
    public string ColumnHyperLinkURL { get; set; }
    public string ColumnHyperLinkPK { get; set; }
}
```

I create a new instance of `List<ColumnData>` (In a different code behind that creates an instance of the user control) and want to pass in values to it, but how do I assign them to specific attributes within the struct object?

I create an instance of the struct using the following code:

```
List<ColumnData> DataItems = new List<ColumnData>();
```

Comment: Why are you using a struct in the first place?

Comment: That ***really*** doesn't look like it should be a struct... I don't think struct means what you *think* it means.

Comment: Because I want to create a collection of the data within the struct, and then do a foreach on it. The repeater outputs either one or two columns at the moment, and I want to make it more dynamic so I can have as many columns that are required.

Comment: @aspdotnetuser A plain ol' class. (See Marc's answer)

Comment: @aspdotnetuser - a class. For the most part, you should forget that structs exist.

Comment: Is there ever a time when using a struct is more useful than using a class?

Comment: @aspdotnetuser [Search StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=when+to+use+a+struct+.net) for "when to use struct".

Comment: As a small note, `ColumnData` sounds like it is already representing a column - personally I'd remove the redundant names, i.e. `Name`, `IsHyperlink`, `LinkUrl` etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change that to a class; all your woes relating to modifying struct properties (etc) will go away.

Alternatively, make it an ***immutable*** struct, and initialize it with the correct values at the point of creation - then the issue is moot, no matter how many times it is subsequently copied.

IMO the first is the right approach here.

Answer (score 18):

This:

```
List<ColumnData> DataItems = new List<ColumnData>();
```

creates a new list.

This:

```
List<ColumnData> DataItems = new List<ColumnData>();
var cd = new ColumnData();
cd.ColumnName = "Taco";
DataItems.Add(cd);
```

creates a new list, a new struct, and adds an item to the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<ColumnData> DataItems = new List<ColumnData>();
```

Is creating the list that holds your structs not your structs itself.

You could use structs here for performance reasons (faster then classes).

```
 ColumnData data = new ColumnData
{
 ColumnName  = "Blaa"
};

DataItems.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

so you need to do this:

```
public void AddToList(ColumnData columnData)
{
  DataItems.Add(columnData);
}
```

and call this method from your other class passing an already created and initialized columnData object.